# How to control images in Vue3 named slots

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

So i made a card component with named slots:

```
<template>
  <div
    class="border border-2 border-gray-500 rounded-3xl w-[15rem] h-[15rem] flex flex-col items-center justify-center shadow-2xl"
  >
    <div
      name="logo"
      class="w-[80%] h-[80%] border border-2 border-gray-500 rounded-3xl overflow-hidden"
    >
      <slot name="logo">
        <img src="" alt="" class="w-full" />
      </slot>
    </div>
    <div name="name" class="font-bold text-gray-500 my-auto">
      <slot name="technology">Technology</slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

This is a card with logo and technology name. But when i use it:

```
 <template #logo>
          <img src="assets\images\hero-section\node.png" alt="" />
        </template>
```

I cant controle the images with classes. When i add classes to the images one by one, it works-like that:

```
>  <template #logo>
>           <img src="assets\images\hero-section\node.png" class="w-[80%]" alt="" />
>         </template>
```

But when i move this class="w-[80%]" to the named slot, it works no more.. Any class that i write to the img tag inside slot doesnt work. How do i universally control images in slots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to place the `w-[80%]` class on the `<img>` you pass into the slot. The `<img>` element in the `<slot name="logo">` is a placeholder when no `<template #logo>` is passed and has no effect on the `<img>` you pass into the slot since the content of the slot is completely replaced. Any class names you apply to the placeholder `<img>` makes no difference to the passed `<img>` element.

If you would always like an image in the `logo` slot, you could instead [use a prop](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html) for the `<img>`, thus allowing you to enforce the `class` attribute value:

```js
<template>
  <div …>
    <div … >
      <img :src="logo" alt="" class="w-[80%]" />
    </div>
    …
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps(['logo']);
</script>

<!-- or -->

<script>
export default {
  props: ['logo'],
}
</script>

<!-- etc. -->
```

And then in to use it:

```js
<Card logo="assets\images\hero-section\node.png">
  …
</Card>
```

Comment: thanks sir for your answer and time, i will try to make a card with one slot for text and prop for image